# Как записать 4 8 битных переменных в одну 32 битную

Tags: c

Подскажите, можно ли записать это более компактно?

```
uint32_t val = 0;
val = byte4;
val=val<<8;
val |= byte3;
val=val<<8;
val |= byte2;
val=val<<8;
val |= byte1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Схема Горнера:

> uint32_t val = (((uint32_t)byte4 << 8 | byte3) << 8 | byte2) << 8 | byte1;

Сумма "степеней":

> uint32_t val = (uint32_t)byte4 << 24 | (uint32_t)byte3 << 16 | (uint32_t)byte2 << 8 | byte1;

**P.S.** Добавлены приведения чтобы сделать все вычисления корректными в случае когда переменные `byte*` имеют тип меньший чем `uint32_t`, например `uint8_t`.

Comment: Разве byte4 << 8 не запишет 0 в byte4? Все переменные byte типа uint8_t. Видимо нужно сделать все byteN uint32_t, тогда это будет работать.

Comment: Понял. Надо было уточнить, что код пишется под микроконтроллер. Микросхема с 28 битным выводом соединяется с 4 8 битными портами микроконтроллера.